# Is LocalDB installed independently of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-localdb

I am a Developer.  I thought LocalDB was installed as a component of Visual Studio, which could be used for development purposes.  However, it appears to be installed independently of Visual Studio.

Is it installed as part of SQL Server; SQL Data Tools or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalDB is an optional feature of SQL Server Express edition.  It may be installed by:

1) Selecting the LocalDB feature during installation of [SQL Server Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb)

2) Selecting the .NET desktop development feature during installation of VS 2017. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774739/how-to-install-localdb-2016-along-with-visual-studio-2017), SSDT does not automatically install LocalDB.